# scikit-learn mean value evaluation

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I wanted to predict the ages of Titanic passengers, but I noticed that people often just fill missing age values with the mean age. I wanted to compare my model's performance with the simple mean value approach. First I did something like `mean_absolute_error(actual_age,mean_age_list)`, actual_age is target, and mean_age_list is just list filled with mean value for age. But then I noticed that I used GridSearchCV to build my model, so it would be appropiate to also evaluate mean value of age with cross validation. And this is where problem starts. `cross_val_score` needs proper sklearn estimator implemenation, so I had to build estimator that just returns mean of target training set.

```
class MeanModel(BaseEstimator):
    def fit(self,X,y):
        self.y = y
        
    def predict(self,X):
        return np.full(X.shape[0], self.y.mean()) 

cross_val_score(MeanModel(),age_prediction_data,age_target_data,cv=10,scoring="neg_mean_absolute_error")
```

And my question is:
Is there any more convinient way for this process, or each time I want to use cross validation to compare my model's performance with just simple mean, I need to create sklearn estimator? How do you compare your model to "simple mean value model"?

Answer (score 0):

Dummy estimators, such as `sklearn.dummy.DummyRegressor()`, are provided out of the box. `DummyRegressor()` supports different strategies in addition to mean as well.